# How to use Auth feature of firebase in a a web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate the auth feature of Firebase in my web app, using logon/signup with the Google feature, but I am facing an error. The normal method of login/signup is working.

I have consoled `userData` and email from the below code and found out this Firebase is actually not taking the email that I am selecting from the pop-up.

The error in my console:

> Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window. closed call

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { BsGoogle, BsGithub, BsFacebook } from "react-icons/bs";
import {
  FacebookAuthProvider,
  GithubAuthProvider,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import { firebaseAuth } from "../utils/FirebaseConfig";
import { firebaseLoginRoute } from "../utils/APIRoutes";

export default function SocialLoginButtons() {
  const providers = {
    google: new GoogleAuthProvider(),
    facebook: new FacebookAuthProvider(),
    github: new GithubAuthProvider(),
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const firebaseLogin = async (loginType) => {
    try {
      const provider = providers[loginType];
      const userData = await signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, provider);
      console.log(userData);

      const email = userData.user.email
        ? userData.user.email
        : userData.user.providerData[0].email;

      console.log(email);

      const { data } = await axios.post(firebaseLoginRoute, { email });

      console.log(data);

      if (data.status) {
        console.log("in if");
        localStorage.setItem(
          "chat-app-user",
          JSON.stringify(data.user)
        );

        navigate("/");
      } else {
        console.log("in else");
        navigate("/setUsername");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("out");
    }
  };

  return (
    <SocialLoginContainer>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => firebaseLogin("google")}>
        <BsGoogle />
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => firebaseLogin("facebook")}>
        <BsFacebook />
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => firebaseLogin("github")}>
        <BsGithub />
      </button>
    </SocialLoginContainer>
  );
}

const SocialLoginContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0.1rem solid #4e0eff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;

    &:hover {
      background-color: #4e0eff;
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to explain the difference between what you expect and what actually happens. If the logged data isn't what you expect, then what is it instead?

Comment: @Phil based on my reading, the Sign In with Google flow did not return the email associated with the selected user's account.

Comment: @Mrnerd Does switching to `new GoogleAuthProvider().addScope("email")` instead of just `new GoogleAuthProvider()` solve the problem? It might be that the default information requested does not include the email, just the profile information.

Comment: Good point @samthecodingman. I noticed it's changed some time recently that Google no longer offers the `email` scope by default